# MSSQL 2017 - Inserting large data sets efficiently

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, insert

I am trying to insert large set of data (about one million rows) from CSV file using C# application into database with four tables. In CSV file is about 25% of rows wrong due to duplicating primary keys and each row is decomposed into four tables. Inserting of row from CSV is done by four procedures (each for one table) packed into transaction with try-catch statement. Inserting of 10000 rows takes about one minute, so it's too long. Does exists any faster method to insert large data set and continuosly check data consistency? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is code of my procedures

```
USE semestralka
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_vloz_ridice @crp nchar(9), @jmeno varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT crp, jmeno FROM ridici 
            WHERE crp = @crp AND jmeno = @jmeno)
    INSERT INTO ridici (crp, jmeno)
    VALUES (@crp, @jmeno)
END
```

```
USE semestralka
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_vloz_auto @SPZ nchar(8), @barva int, @vyrobce nvarchar(25), @model nvarchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT SPZ, barva, vyrobce, model FROM auta 
            WHERE SPZ = @SPZ AND barva = @barva AND vyrobce = @vyrobce AND model = @model)
    INSERT INTO auta (SPZ, barva, vyrobce, model)
    VALUES (@SPZ, @barva, @vyrobce, @model)
END
```

```
USE semestralka
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_vloz_branu @brana_jmeno nchar(10), @typ varchar(10), @cena real, @gps_lattitude real, @gps_longtitude real
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT jmeno, typ, cena, gps_lattitude, gps_longtitude  FROM brany
            WHERE jmeno = @brana_jmeno AND typ = @typ AND cena = @cena AND gps_lattitude = @gps_lattitude AND gps_longtitude = @gps_longtitude )
    INSERT INTO brany (jmeno, typ, cena, gps_lattitude, gps_longtitude)
    VALUES (@brana_jmeno, @typ, @cena, @gps_lattitude, @gps_longtitude)
END
```

```
USE semestralka
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_vloz_prujezd @prujezd_datum_cas int, @fk_prujezd_spz nchar(8), @fk_prujezd_crp nchar(9), @fk_gps_lattitude real, @fk_gps_longtitude real, @tachometr_stav int, @palivo_stav real, @napeti_baterie real
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO prujezdy (prujezd_datum_cas, fk_prujezd_spz, fK_prujezd_crp, fk_gps_lattitude, fk_gps_longtitude, tachometr_stav, palivo_stav, napeti_baterie)
    VALUES (@prujezd_datum_cas, @fk_prujezd_spz, @fK_prujezd_crp,  @fk_gps_lattitude, @fk_gps_longtitude, @tachometr_stav, @palivo_stav, @napeti_baterie)
END
```

```
USE semestralka
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_super_insert @SPZ nchar(8), @barva int, @vyrobce nvarchar(25), @model nvarchar(40),
                                @crp nchar(9), @jmeno varchar(50),
                                @brana_jmeno nchar(10), @typ varchar(10), @cena real, @gps_lattitude real, @gps_longtitude real,
                                @prujezd_datum_cas int, @tachometr_stav int, @palivo_stav real, @napeti_baterie real, @output bit OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @output = 0
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_vloz_auto @SPZ, @barva, @vyrobce, @model
        EXEC sp_vloz_ridice @crp, @jmeno
        EXEC sp_vloz_branu @brana_jmeno, @typ, @cena, @gps_lattitude, @gps_longtitude
        EXEC sp_vloz_prujezd @prujezd_datum_cas, @SPZ, @crp, @gps_lattitude, @gps_longtitude, @tachometr_stav, @palivo_stav, @napeti_baterie
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN @output
    END CATCH
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    SET @output = 1
    RETURN @output
END
```

Comment: Faster than what?   You haven't told us what these stored procedures are doing.   Show us your code.

Comment: Have you tried SSIS? A proper ETL service would likely be "better", however @TabAlleman is right here, we don't have anything to work with right now.

Comment: You can use the SQLBulkCopy class. You can set it to KeepIdentity as part of the bulkcopyoptions argument, but other data validation will need to be done separately I believe. You will need to build a column mapping before inserting if your columns specs do not match. This is quite a project for a SO post.

Comment: Another option is to have a stored proc do SQL Server bulk insert to a staging table and then (1) validate the data and (2) run your `insert into...select from` statements off the staging table. SSIS is preferable if you can manage it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set based operations instead of line by line (or cursor/foreach) statements. You are currently executing a stored procedure that executes another 4 stored procedures inside a transaction, just to insert 4 lines in 4 different tables. Executing this by thousands of times is extremely slow compared to a set base solution, in which you do all rows at the same time, without sacrificing your business rules.

Use a Bulk Insert command (from your C# app) into a Staging Table, which is a table to hold temporal data before inserting it on your final tables. You would have 4 different staging tables in your case.

These staging tables will have no constraints, keys, triggers or any other mechanism that might delay the insert operation. Bulk inserts work very fast on such tables.

After you insert your CSV on the staging tables, you can use SQL to validate and insert the records on your final table (on a set basis, not 1 by 1). You can create or enable (rebuild) indexes on your staging tables if you need to do joins or particular filters on certain columns.

Staging tables could be volatile, so you may truncate them on each run if you need.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is much faster.